# Открытие проводника и запись пути к файлу

Tags: java, файлы, файловая-система

Если с открытием проводника еще +- сложилось(код приведу ниже), то сейчас хочу что б при выборе определенного файла и нажатии кнопки ОК в определенную переменную записывался путь к этому файлу иначиналось считывание. 
Буду благодарна за подсказку метода, который может реализовать подобное).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File ("c:");
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try {
        desktop.open(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста](https://www.journaldev.com/848/java-file-path-absolute-canonical), читайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop API выполняет несколько другую функцию, он работает с системой, чтобы вызвать выбор файла нужен примерно такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Open File Example");

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(), "File name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Метод

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Подстраивает окно выбора файла под вид системы. А окно выбора файла создаётся классом `JFileChooser`. `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` - служит для отображения окна с выводом.

Путь файла хранится в `chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()`.